# Outlook macro to check domain name

Tags: vba, outlook

trying to add a check to my macro that checks the domain of the recipients email (the 'To:')

```
Dim olTo As String

If InStr(olTo, "example.com") Then
Exit Sub
```

If the recipient email address matches my domain I want it to end macro and send, else I want to do other checks, which I have working.

The above doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add a comparison, try this:

```
Dim olTo As String

If InStr(olTo, "example.com") > 0 Then
Exit Sub
```

Else, try to debug to see what Instr(olTo, "domain.com") returns.

Regards,